# Is EOT character sitting over terminal promp an issue?

Tags: linux, sqlite, terminal

Warning: you know how they say "there's not such thing as a stupid question"? Well, this one is, or, I suspect it's really minor, but wth, why not ask. Search engines didn't bring me anything remotely useful, though that could be bad searchterm-fu.

I recently downloaded sqlite3 onto Ubuntu 10 to start learning SQL commands. I un-tar'd 3.7.12.01 and make installed.
After creating a test.db with `create table test (id)` I decided to see what I'd get if I `cat` it. Just because.
The result is an EOT character (u+0004) *which is sitting right over my prompt*. Illustrated screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKW32.jpg

I realise this is not the type of file you would use `cat` on. I only want to know, before I go further,

**does the strange placement of this character signal any future issues when actually playing around with SQL, or some issue with newlines, or fonts (this is monofur set at a high font size) or similar?**

I've never seen a result character placed directly over my prompt before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character is placed over your prompt, because it is a double-width character, and terminals in general are not good at handling double-width characters. It does not mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are [some control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) which can do very funny things with your terminal, such as changing colors, fonts etc.

But none of them do really harm - you should be able to `reset` your terminal to a healthy state, or close it and open a new one.